# plink.exe - force timeout for remote operations

Tags: timeout, remote-connection, plink

Have script which daily reading configs from bunch of network devices utilizing plink.exe. Time by time, some device have stucked internal process which provide backup data and plink instance (and thus whole script) stuck until CTRL+C is pressed. Is there any way to push plink.exe to set timeout for remote operations? Now only SSH protocol layer timeout are reported by plink.exe, but this is not my case because SSH connection and login runs over successfully, but remote command execution stuck whole process.

I cant find anything helpful in plink.exe help

Comment: Would it work if you had a separate process that monitored your plink.exe script and killed it after a period of time rather than relying on plink.exe to do it? If so, would something like this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977026/how-to-set-timeout-for-a-command-in-cmd

Comment: I am aware of this solution but looking for something more reliable (as killing stucked process is not)

Comment: Would you consider using something other than plink? Winscp can be similarly scripted and has a timeout option.

Comment: I wrote feature request to authors of plink, so will see. Know winscp, but prefer small, single purpose, utilities without installing process. Now looking for some putty ports (like Quest putty) with this feature enabled.

Comment: While not as small as plink.exe, winscp does have a portable exe and I've had good success with the .NET assembly for Powershell for having more control over an sftp-reliant application

Answer (score 0):

What about to ping the device before you connect with plink.
Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28589578/15458891) I got a perfect function:

```
set "_ip=localhost"
set "_ip=192.168.1.1"
ping %_ip% -n 1 -4 | find /i "TTL=">nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo ping %_ip% failure
    ) else ( 
    echo ping %_ip% success
    )
```

- `-4` to force using IPv4 (as e.g. ping `localhost` replies IPv6 with no `TTL=` output)
- `| find /i "TTL="` as `find` command raises `errorlevel` well
- `>nul` to suppress undesired output

Just replace the `echo ping %_ip% success` with your plink commands.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This powershell code start windows process [here ping.exe to easier testing] and terminate it if it does not end until preset time [here 3 seconds - 3000 miliseconds] out.

```
powershell.exe "Start-Process 'ping.exe' -ArgumentList '127.0.0.1', '-t' -NoNewWindow -PassThru | %% { if(-not $_.WaitForExit(3000)) { $_.Kill() } }"
```

Its an oneliner to easy use in hybrid batch/ps scripts

Answer (score -1):

There is no `plink` option for this.

But there are many workarounds, for example if you have have GNU `timeout` installed

```
/usr/bin/timeout 2s plink -no-antispoof $me@$host hostname -s
```

Comment: Downvote, bacuse this question if for plink.exe [windows executable], not a linux one

Comment: I have cmder installed (on windows), which has "linux toolset" installed. That is one of the ways to deal with life on windows.